# Printing with Javascript Preview Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I am trying to print using jQuery plugin: https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print

So I've styled the page to look like a A4 sheet (*210x297mm*):

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
#page {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
}
</style>
```

Also, I am using **Bootstrap v4**, but when I trigger the print function the preview shows me a completely different sheet:

This is how the HTML page looks:
[image: HTML page]

But instead, the preview (and the print) looks like:

[image: Printing Preview]

I think they should look the same. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: share your code please

Comment: I already did that, what code?